# How to Avoid html tags in an XML document

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I have an XML document, the format of which looks something like below;

```
<root>
<DETAIL Replaces="XYZ" />
<DETAIL Description="Problem:<br><br>CRS750 dumps when panel F is opened<br><br>>>y" />
<DETAIL StepsToReproduce="ABC" />
</root>
```

Using the below function I'm able to convert the above loaded XML Doc to desired format;

```
Function ProcessDetail(ByVal xmlText As String) As String
   xtr = New XmlTextReader("GetXMLFileLocation")
        xtr.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None
        xmlDoc.Load(xtr)
        xtr.Close()

    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlText)
    Dim sDetail As New StringBuilder()
    sDetail.Append("<DETAIL>")
    For Each detailNode As XmlNode In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DETAIL")
        If Not detailNode.Attributes Is Nothing Then
            For Each attribute As XmlAttribute In detailNode.Attributes
 sDetail.Append("<" & attribute.Name.ToUpper & ">" & attribute.Value & "</" &    
 attribute.Name.ToUpper & ">")
            Next
        End If
    Next
    sDetail.Append("</DETAIL>")
    Return sDetail.ToString()
End Function
```

Question :- Since my description node under DETAIL has some 'HTML' tags , it gives the below error . Please help me avoid that and give the below output.

```
ERROR MESSAGE : '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 
1,  position 1326.


DESIRED OUTPUT :
 <root>
 <DETAIL>
 <REPLACES>XYZ</REPLACES> 
 <DESCRIPTION>Problem:<br><br>CRS750 dumps when panel F is opened<br> 
 <br>>>y</DESCRIPTION>
 <STEPSTOREPRODUCE>ABC<STEPSTOREPRODUCE/>
 <root>
```

Answer (score 0):

html-in-xml would be an invalid XML document, and need to be fixed at the source generating the xml. e.g. it's impossible for an XML parser to tell what should be part of the XML and what's simply an html tag. e.g. xml should look like

```
<somexmltag>&lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph with embedded &lt;i&gt;italics&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/p>&gt;</somexmltag>
```

or using CDATA:

```
<somexmltag><![CDATA[<p>This is a paragraph with embedded <i>italics</i></p>]]></somexmltag>
```

Comment: Hi Marc .. Thank you for your answer . However, I used CDATA like shown in my XML file like shown below . Am I missing any syntax ?? It gives me same error.

Comment: <DETAIL IXS_KB_ID="<![CDATA[<br>1250532]]" />

Comment: `]]>` for the closing tag. and I see I've got a typo on the opening one. fixing that. should two `[` on the opener.

Comment: Why are you using an XML API to *read* the document but not to write it? You should only be doing string manipulation on XML data when you're working in an environment that doesn't provide an XML manipulation API.

Comment: also... too tired to check, but I don't think you can have cdata blocks within a tag's attribute.

Comment: @MarcB: Looks like CDATA is valid anywhere character data is allowed, so it sounds like it should work as an attribute value. His value above is invalid, though, as CDATA is closed by `]]>`, but he only has `]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use &lt; instead of <, &amp; instead of &, and optionally &gt; instead of >, also &quot; for " and/or &apos; for '

If you are generating (or escaping) the HTML, make sure you change the and-signs before the other characters! :-)

You cannot use CDATA sections inside an attribute. Also, CDATA sections sometimes occur in HTML, and they don't nest, leading to potential code breakage or even security holes if you are not careful. (CDATA injection attack).